# Sitecore Experience editor showing raw JSON data

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, experience-editor

I am using a simple MVC sitecore project. I just given only one field in rendering page. When i try to view in "Experience Editor" its showing some raw JSON Data like below.[image]

I have used [this post](http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/08/sitecore-page-editor-mode-renders.html)

to solve this. when i include that **webedit.css** in my main layout then the Raw data vanished. But i am not able to see the Editing Ribbon. But when i choose Experience Editor from desktop its showing all Default contents correctly along with the editing Ribbon(Default Page).

Can anyone tell me why i am not able to see that editing ribbon on my page?

Comment: It's always like that? Or just after a save?

Comment: Seems like you have a buggy deployment. If this a new project? Does it happen on a clean install of Sitecore?

Comment: Yes its happend on a clean install of Sitecore. And its always like that only.

Comment: if this is data from template field, did you pass the data as HtmlString or call the dataType as `@Html.Raw("")`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your layout razor cshtml file has valid HTML markup skeleton in place.  Please make sure at the very minimum your page is formatted like this:

```
@using Sitecore.MVC

<html>
    <body>
         @Html.Sitecore().Etc...
         etc...
    </body>
</html>
```

This should eliminate the big chunk of JSON on top and enable all page editor UI elements.